# MongoDB find where resoult + value > when 100

Tags: mongodb

I have the following db structure:

```
 [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "family": "First Family",
      "kids": [
        {
          "name": "David",
          "age": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Moses",
          "age": 15
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "family": "Second Family",
      "kids": [
        {
          "name": "Sara",
          "age": 17
        },
        {
          "name": "Miriam",
          "age": 45
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I want to select all families that have a kid that his age + 10 is bigger then 30.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Please add the expected output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

please find query below

```
db.collection.find({ "kids.age":{$gt:20}})
```

Comment: Thanks but my code is just an example.
 i need the exact query that is in the question